# C# Concat two chars in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to create a little algorithm to concat two chars in my char array.

In fact, I need to enumerate all my char in my array with a loop.
I have this string number: "**1819**12**0108041**" converted to char array with **.ToCharArray()** and I want to, when I enumerate all my chars, concatenate "*12*" in my loop (5th & 6th position).

Result needed (output of my loop):

```
>1
>8
>1
>9
>12
>0
>1
>0
>8
>0
>4
>1
```

I don't know how can I make it in code.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you know that `1, 2` should be combined, but not `1, 8` or `1, 0`, or any other pattern?

Comment: Always 5 and 6 chars position (or 4&5 in C#)

Comment: Adding values to an array while looping over it is arguably the worst time to do it. Is there a reason you can't, say, note the index of the place you want to insert the characters and do the insertion later?

Comment: Please always show the exact input you have and the exact output you want. You've specified that you have a string like `1819 12 0108041` in your question, but that's not correct. The string is actually `1819120108041`, without the spaces. If you need to emphasize the 1 and 2, bold them or italicize them. Don't add spaces that aren't there.

Comment: @PatrickTucci it's simply because I wanted to put style (Italic) on 12

Comment: @Naografix that's fine, italicize 12 then. But don't add spaces that aren't there. It makes your question more difficult to answer. Most people can tell the difference between bold and italicized text; there's no need to separate the two with spaces.

Comment: @PatrickTucci Ok thank you. My bad

Comment: And you know the result needs to be a string array not a character array?

Comment: @IanMercer Yes my result needs to be an array because I need to use it to calculate something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the code sample given below. You can convert the result to `string[]` using `ToArray()` or to a `List<string>` using `ToList()` methods.

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Enumerate(string val)
    {
        var i = 0;
        var pattern = string.Empty;
        foreach(var ch in val)
        {
            i++;
            if (i == 5)
            {
                pattern += ch;
            }
            else if (i == 6)
            {
                yield return pattern + ch;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return ch.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Really thank you. I like how you use your returns. I made little update to convert this list to char array